# Java Support For C# Indexers

Tags: c#, java

How can Java support C# indexers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at this time, however this may provide you with some information on the currently accepted Java way (which unfortunately is just methods):

[Java VS C# : Indexer](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/indexer.html)

Good luck.